# Firebase function not triggering

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function

```
exports.testfunction = functions.database
    .ref("a/{aId}/b/{bId}/c/{dId}/{eId}")
    .onWrite(event => {
        console.log("Function Called");
    });
```

This function is not being called, when a write at the `a/{aId}/b/{bId}/c/{dId}/{eId}` is made. Can't find the damn issue.

Comment: show us your database

Comment: Can't show the actual database. The variables used do have a meaning. I assure that there are no spelling mistakes. @PeterHaddad

Comment: no I mean, the referenced location is probably wrong that is why it does not get triggered when a write is made

Comment: There is no way to determine what is going wrong from the information you shared. The code looks fine, so the problem likely comes from the context in which you deploy or try to trigger it. The best way to ensure we can help with such issues is by [creating a standalone MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would also solve the problem that you can't show your database.